# How to create sub pages with ID's

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website with a large amount of information (news articles). So I have a list of news articles that have an intro and a header. When I click on one it brings up the full article, the way I did it was with ajax so it happens dynamically, but that left me with the problem of not being able to bookmark the larger picture of the article.

I couldn't find a good tutorial on how to do this, I thought it would be good to do it the way I have seen it on other sites (the url being something like `index.php?id=512435345`, like auto-generated sub pages). I don't even know what that solution is called, so I couldn't find anything I could use.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would help me out a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we create an article it is stored in the db with a unique ID. Then the developer creates a single page which is pretty a much a template that shows the title, description, date, likes, shares, etc. The page uses the unique ID of the post that was stored in the Database to get it's likes, shares and all the things!

And yes, they are the auto-generated sub-ids but are generated by the Database itself.

I would recommend you creating a single page like `article.php` and send a ID of the article by fetching it from the database thorugh the `super global ($_GET)` <-- if using PHP. Then make queries or a query to get the data from the database's table and display it to the end user in a nice and clean manner.